# Speed at which methanol dissolve in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

Suppose that in a container of volume V we pour V1 of methanol and V2 of water (V2>V1), supposing that V2 is big enough that all the methanol will be dissolved, do we have to mix them mechanically or the diffusion will be enough if we want them to mix in seconds?

Comment: Methanol is infinitely soluble in water and vice versa. If you mean how long does it take for the solution to be relatively uniform, it will be more than several seconds. You should stir.

Comment: Is their a formula calculating the exact time and rate?

Comment: No. The way you pour it is going to matter. The size and shape of the container. You're basically modelling diffusion which can be done, but it's pretty dependent on initial conditions...

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Zhe, the rate of the mixing of methanol in water (or the other way around) depends (among other parameters) on the rate of addition, the geometry of the vessel, if / how the solutions are mixed by a stirrer.  In addition, this process [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion) is dependent on temperature and gradients of concentration.  One approach to quantify diffusion is based on the differential [Fick's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion) by determination of the diffusion coefficient.

As difficult it may appear, the diffusion of methanol in water was determined experimentally, as [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100270a039) and [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je00002a024), for example.  If you do not have access to a university library, NIH / HHS made a more recent reference available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4212651/), and a more general value is given [here](http://www.gsi-net.com/en/publications/gsi-chemical-database/single/343-methanol.html)